# Facebook share via android app - change the url of "shared via <AppName>"

Tags: android, facebook, share

When someone shares something from an Android app called e.g. TestApp, the facebook post is going to write "shared via TestApp", and it's clickable.

Is it possible to change that link to something apart from a in-site facebook app? Change it for example to my android app's url in the play store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible via Android Deep Linking - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/

Comment: I changed the `Website with Facebook Login` and it now redirects to the url. Thanks m8!

Comment: What is your specific question ? Is it not covered here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app.

Comment: Deep linking is deprecated now, and I can't get the point of new "App Links" :/